# Folders missing from project, don't show up even after using Show All Files

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

In Visual Studio 2019, I have come across the issue in which a public repository does not show all of the folders, but rather just displays all files as-is even though in reality they are within those folders.

All of the solutions online point towards pressing "Show All Files" and utilizing the "Include in Project" button, however, even after pressing "Show All Files", the folders refuse to show up.